# How can I recursively get the IDs of all the parent elements in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have the following PHP multidimensional array, which is designed to be recursed through:

```
$arr = array(
  array(
    'id' => 1,
    'kids' => array(
      array(
        'id' => 11,
        'kids' => array(
          array(
            'id' => 101,
            'kids' => array(),
          ),
        ),
      ), // please note this is a sample
    ),   // it could have any number of levels
  ),
);
```

How, given an ID value of 101, can I figure out that IDs 1 and 11 are parents of that element in the multidimensional array?

Comment: Any tree search algo should work. For PHP implementation, look for instance http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2012/09/17/computer-algorithms-graph-depth-first-search/

Comment: Per @M.Page comment.  Here's some reading on the idea. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal For example, you can do a depth first search with a base case of the ID you're looking for. Then you can pass the parent ID's back up as you return.

Comment: I would also recommend an alteration in your array set up: Make the keys the id values, and then just use them to transverse. Let me see if I can get quick example working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a function that may be helpful for you.

```
function get_parents($target, $array)
{
    $parents_id = false;
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if (empty($array)) 
            return;
        if ($item['id'] == $target)
            return array();
        else
            $parents_id = get_parents($target, $item['kids']);
        if (is_array($parents_id))
            array_unshift($parents_id, $item['id']);

    }
    return $parents_id;
}
```

For each item in your array, if it is empty, just return nothing. If it is the item you are looking for, return an empty array in which we will add parent's ids, else keep looking deeper. At this point, if $parents_id is an array, is because you have found your target key, so add parents ids to the beginning of your array

Call this function like this: `get_parents('101', $arr);`

In your example, the result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 11
)
```

If the target key is not found, the function returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

this program work just in first array deep
and not work by this

$arr = array(
  array(
    'id' => 1, //start root
    'parent' => array(
      array(
        'id' => 2,
        'parent' => array(
          array(
            'id' => 3,
            'parent' => array(array('id' => 4,'parent' => array()),array('id' => 5,'parent' => array())),
          ),

```
      array(
        'id' => 6,
        'parent' => array(array('id' => 7,'parent' => array()),array('id' => 8,'parent' => array())),
      ),

     ),
  ), 
        array(
    'id' => 9,
    'parent' => array(
      array(
        'id' => 10,
        'parent' => array(array('id' => 11,'parent' => array()),array('id' => 12,'parent' => array())),
      ),

      array(
        'id' => 13,
        'parent' => array(array('id' => 14,'parent' => array()),array('id' => 15,'parent' => array())),
      ),

     ),
  ), 

),  //end root
```

),

);